# How to remove current_user from index of all users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In otherwords, in my app I have an index that displays the number of total users I'd like to exclude the current_user from this list..

I've used the following code to prevent the user.name and user.profile_photo from showing successfully:

```
<% unless user.hidden_for?(current_user) || user.blocked_for?(current_user) || user == current_user %>
```

However, it still says Showing 2 users when it only shows the profile photo and name of the other user, it should really only be saying Showing one user and not include me there.

Here is the line of code that ultimately needs the fix:

```
 <h4 class="events_counter">
            <%= @users.any? ? "Showing #{pluralize(@users.size, 'people')}" : "No users to show" %>
          </h4>
```

Any help would be awesome!! 
Cheers!

Update: (Here's the current relevant index action)

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
    if params[:search]
      terms = params[:search][:terms] || nil
      min_age = params[:search][:age_min] || nil
      max_age = params[:search][:age_max] || nil
      zipcode = params[:search][:zipcode] || nil
      distance = params[:search][:distance] || nil
      education_id = params[:search][:education_id] || nil
      # @ethnicity_id = params[:search][:ethnicity_id] || nil
      ethnicity_ids = params[:search][:cat_ids].split('').uniq || nil
      gender = params[:search][:gender] || nil
      @users = User.active.scoped_by_search(terms, min_age, max_age, education_id, ethnicity_ids, gender)
    else
      @users = User.active.page params[:page]
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `Rails 4.x`,

Assuming that your action name is `index` where you set the `@users` instance variable, you could do something like this:

```
def index
  #...
    @users = User.active.scoped_by_search(terms, min_age, max_age, education_id, ethnicity_ids, gender).where.not(id: current_user.id)
  else
    @users = User.active.where.not(id: current_user.id).page params[:page]
  #... 
end
```

Here, if you have a `current_user` then `@users` will contain all the users except the `current_user`. Otherwise, `@users` will have all the users.

Also, you don't require any checks in your view, i.e.,

```
 <% unless user.hidden_for?(current_user) || user.blocked_for?(current_user) || user == current_user %>
```

**is no longer required so you can remove it safely.**

Also, `@users.size` would give the correct count of other users (excluding `current_user`).

Comment: @user3399101 Thanks for sharing `index` action. I have updated answer accordingly. Let me know if that works.

Answer (score 1):

Recommend excluding `current_user` in the query instead of view.  For example in controller:

```
@users = User.where('id != ?', current_user.id)
```

However, if you need to keep the current user in the `@users` array then, use `reject` to exclude the current user as:

```
@users.reject { |u| u.id == current_user.id }
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I'm getting a Nilclass error on reject, I've updated the post with the current index action, hope that helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest building a new array of visible_users somewhere else.

Here is a way to get that array based on your current logic and array.

```
visible_users = @users.reject{|user| user.hidden_for?(current_user) || user.blocked_for?(current_user) || user == current_user}
```

Hopefully that helps.